# Insert Into with multiple columns and multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, insert, multiple-columns, multiple-value

```
INSERT INTO MANAGING(SUPID, EMPID)
VALUES (76, 1, 4, 8);
```

currently this is the code I have, I just simply want to have the 1,4,8 go into the `EMPID` as three separate values.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Insert them using separate scripts.

Simply try this.

```
INSERT INTO MANAGING(SUPID, EMPID) VALUES (76, 1);
INSERT INTO MANAGING(SUPID, EMPID) VALUES (76, 4);
INSERT INTO MANAGING(SUPID, EMPID) VALUES (76, 8);
```

Comment: The only issue I have is that SUPID is a primary key, so it'll let me put in the first one but not the other two

Comment: @Xavier.code, in that case you have to create a separate table for Employees, and set the SupId as `Foreign Key`, or change the primary key to `Composite key`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your db engine, you can do it also using

```
INSERT INTO MANAGING(SUPID, EMPID) VALUES (76, 1),(76, 4),(76, 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have emp table

```
INSERT INTO MANAGINS(SUPID,EMPID) SELECT 76, ID FROM EMP_TABLE
```